# Klingt Reich-Ranicki wie ein Deutschmuttersprachler?

Tags: pronunciation

[Hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnM_CdlVTi4) ist eine rührende Lobrede auf Heinrich Böll vom berühmten Literaturkritiker Reich-Ranicki.
Dieser Kritiker spricht offensichtlich ein äußerst elegantes Deutsch, obwohl seine Muttersprache polnisch war.
Meine Frage ist: hört man ihm an, dass er kein Deutschmuttersprachler ist?
Mit anderen Worten: gibt es Gegenden in Deutschland oder Österreich in denen   Leute ähnlich wie Reich-Ranicki deutsch aussprechen ?

**Abklärung**
Dass Reich-Ranicki ein geniale Figur war ist selbstverständlich.
Meine Frage ist: würde ein Automechaniker oder ein Kellner, die nie von Reich-Ranicki gehört haben, nach einem kurzen, alltäglichen  Gespräch über einen Wagen oder eine Speisekarte merken, dass Reich-Ranicki nicht in einer deutschsprechenden Umgebung geboren wurde.
Ich weiß sehr gut, dass diese Frage nicht sehr präzise ist, aber ich hoffe dennoch, dass ein wohlwollender Benutzer dieser Site schon versteht, was ich meine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69934/discussion-on-question-by-georges-elencwajg-klingt-reich-ranicki-wie-ein-deutsch).

Comment: Deine Frage ist komplizierter als es auf den ersten Blick scheint, gerade mit deiner Ergänzung (wie hört sich Reich-Ranicki für einen "typischen Automechaniker" an). Es kommt hier ganz darauf an, welche Spracherfahrung, speziell im Kontakt mit Leuten aus Gegenden, wo man Deutsch anders spricht, dein Automechaniker de facto hat. Ein Mensch, der nur in seinem Städtchen aufgewachsen ist, dort nie (außer zum Urlaub auf Mallorca) herauskam und also keine Erfahrung mit Aussprachevarianten hat, würde vermutlich denken "Reich-Ranicki ist ein Ausländer". Aber das ist ein sehr theoretisches Szenario.

Comment: Die Prämisse ist wohl falsch. Er war Deutschmuttersprachler. Soweit das Elternhaus Umgebung ist, war es wohl auch eine deutschsprachige Umgebung. Kannst Du auf einen Audioschnpsel verweisen, der daran Zweifel aufkommen lässt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich denke man kann sehr wohl hören, dass Deutsch nicht seine *Muttersprache* war. Ich möchte das garnicht positiv oder negativ werten. Für mich ist das ganz klar ein subjektives Empfinden,  hier gibt es kein richtig oder falsch (wenn ich auch niemanden kenne, der eine ähnliche Aussprache gehabt hätte bzw. hat).

Ich wende das einfach mal auf mich an: Auch wenn mein English verhandlungssicher ist, hört man dennoch (wahrscheinlich auch in 40 Jahren noch), dass die englische Sprache (weder BE noch AE) nicht meine Muttersprache ist. Da können die Sätze noch so verschnörkelt, elegant und grammatikalisch korrekt sein.

Comment: Danke blablubb, das ist genau die Art von Antwort, die ich erwartete. Meine Frage hat in der Tat nichts mit positiver oder negativer Wertung zu tun.

Comment: Das freut mich:)

Comment: Für mich ist ie *Muttersprachenfrage* nicht so einfach. Ja, Reich-Ranickis Aussprache verweist auf die Gegend von Polen. Jedoch würde ich es (ebenso subjektiv und fern von richtig/falsch, wie Du deine Auffassung vorträgst) durchaus für plausibel halten, dass eben in Reich-Ranickis Elternhaus genau auf diese Weise Deutsch als Haupt- oder auch Erstsprache gesprochen wurde. (Ich gebe aber zu, dass ich, obwohl ich jetzt natürlich kurz zu Reich-Ranickis Biographie kundig gemacht habe, nicht weiß, wie man im Hause der Unternehmersfamilie David und Helene Reich bei Tisch gesprochen hat.)

Comment: Ich bestreite, dass das eine Frage des subjektiven Empfindens ist. Wer als erste Sprache über eine gewisse Zeit Deutsch lernt, hat als Muttersprache Deutsch - ob er lispelt, nuschelt und nasal spricht oder nicht. Wir kennen Dein Englisch nicht, aber MRR spricht Hochdeutsch - ich bin aber bereit mich einem Video- oder Audiostück zu widmen, welches mir das Gegenteil zeigt.

Comment: Das ist Deine Definition von Muttersprache und ich bin sicher, dass es für die Muttersprache keine universell geltende Definition gibt (deswegen unterscheidet sich Deine scheinbar auch von der des Fragestellers, der MRR ja die "Nichtmuttersprachlichkeit" im Deutschen unterstellt. Wie man dann behaupten kann, das sei keine Frage des subjektiven Empfindens, entzieht sich absolut meinem Verständnis. Ich finde es vielmehr subjektiv ziemlich daneben, meine Antwort, die scheinbar den Nerv des Fragestellers traf, aufgrund abweichender eigener Meinung runterzuwerten (sorry für die Unterstellung).

Answer (score 8):

Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, ob man Reich-Ranicki die deutsche Muttersprache "aberkennen" kann. Er wuchs in Polen als Sohn eines gebildeten jüdischen Polen, der Deutsch, Jiddisch und Polnisch sprach, und einer deutschen Mutter, die (fast) kein Polnisch oder Jiddisch sprach, dafür aber auf deutschsprachige Erziehung großen Wert legte, auf. Ich gehe davon aus, dass im Haushalt mehr deutsch und jiddisch als polnisch gesprochen wurde. Nach seiner Aussage gab es keine Bücher auf Polnisch im Haus, nur deutsche. Er besuchte (nur) deutsche Schulen, zog mit 9 Jahren nach Berlin und kehrte erst mit 19 nach Warschau zurück. Auch sein eigentlicher Nachname (Reich, Ranicki ist angenommen und nach eigener Aussage "nur ausgedacht") ist offenkundig deutscher Herkunft.

Ich denke, das erfüllt zumindestens viele Bedingungen für einen Muttersprachler, auch wenn er nicht auf deutschem Staatsgebiet aufgewachsen ist (Was für alle Südtiroler auch gilt, die sich aber sicher die deutsche Muttersprache nicht aberkennen lassen würden).

Seine Sprache war, was für einen Literaturkritiker wohl unabdingbar ist, grammatisch absolut über jeden Zweifel erhaben, hörte sich allerdings vom Akzent her (für mich) wie eine Mischung aus ostpreußischem Dialekt und Jiddisch an - Obwohl von ihm nicht überliefert wäre, dass er jemals Jiddisch gesprochen hätte. Einen wirklich "polnischen Akzent" höre ich für mich nicht heraus. Es kann durchaus sein, dass das ein angewöhntes Kunstidiom war - Ich würde es ihm zutrauen. Ich habe auch den Eindruck, dass er diesen Akzent in späteren Jahren, als man ihn öfters im "literarischen Quartett" im Fernsehen sah, regelrecht gepflegt hat.

Nach eigener Aussage sprach er lieber deutsch als polnisch, während seine Frau mit ihm grundsätzlich polnisch sprach - Auch das mag seinen Akzent beeinflusst haben.

Ginge es nicht um die Person Reich-Ranicki, sondern "nur" um seine Sprache, würde ich ihn möglicherweise für einen in einer fremdsprachlichen Umgebung isoliert (z.B. in einer Großfamilie) aufgewachsenen Muttersprachler halten. Sein Umgang mit der Sprache ist zu gewandt, als dass man Deutsch bei ihm für eine Zweitsprache halten könnte.

Comment: Bist Du mit ostdeutschen Dialekten bewandert? Sein Geburtsort liegt, meinen Karten zufolge, in Westpreußen/Pommern, nicht Ostpreußen.

Comment: @userunknown Ich glaube, in der Frage geht es nicht darum, welchen Dialekt *genau* der Herr sprach (oder ob es den überhaupt gibt). In seiner Biografie wird das Gebiet um seine Heimatsstadt Wloclavek "Neuostpreussen" genannt. Bis heute hat es bestimmt viele andere Namen gehabt.

Comment: Vorab: Eine Muttersprache kann man niemandem aberkennen, allenfalls absprechen. Und eine Frage: "Einen wirklich "polnischen Akzent" höre ich für mich nicht heraus. Es kann durchaus sein, dass das ein angewöhntes Kunstidiom war - Ich würde es ihm zutrauen." Also etwas, dass Du nicht hörst soll ein Kunstidiom sein? Und gepflegt hat er es auch noch? Aber hören tust Du's nicht? Ich verstehe es nicht. "Einen polnischen Akzent höre ich nicht heraus" wäre eine Aussage gewesen, aber _poln. A._ setzt Du in Anführungsstriche, weil es etwas anderes ist. Dieses relativierst Du noch mal durch _wirklich_. …

Comment: …Und dann noch weiter durch _für mich_. Hätte eine Relativierung nicht genügt? Worauf ich eigentlich hinaus will: Ich habe mir noch mal einen Videoausschnitt angeschaut. Er spricht hochdeutsch. Wenn man es wortgetreu transkribieren würde wäre gar keine regionale Zuordnung möglich, zumindest über weite Passagen. Nur der Singsang der Stimme, ein wenig lispeln, nuscheln, ein wenig nasales ist unverwechselbar MRR. Ganz selten vielleicht mal ein Idiom dazwischen. Vielleicht wenn er Witze erzählt, und dann mehr Mundart rauslässt. Oder ist es ein jiddischer Einfluss? Kann ich nicht sagen.

Answer (score 2):

Um es mal mit einer Antwort auf die eigentliche Frage zu versuchen:

Für mich als Deutschmuttersprachler aus - ursprünglich - dem Südwesten der BRD klingt Reich-Ranicki zuerst einmal einfach sehr charakteristisch nach Reich-Ranicki.

Ich habe mir, obwohl er natürlich jahrzehntelang prominent in der Öffentlichkeit sicht- und hörbar war, nie Gedanken gemacht, ob Deutsch seine *Muttersprache* (oder Erstsprache oder Kinderzeitprache oder wie auch immer) sei oder ob er Deutsch sich erst später oder in anderem soziolinguistischem Funktionszusammenhang als dem Elternhause angeeignet habe. Die Perfektion des Satzbaus legte aber nahe, dass Deutsch - z.b. als Literatursprache - schon früh bei ihm eine wesentliche Rolle gespielt haben muss. Seine Aussprachebesonderheiten verwiesen dabei, und auch ohne eigentliche Beschäftigung mit seiner Biografie, auf irgendwo nordöstlich der Nachwende-BRD (also am ehesten irgendwo in und um Polen).

Aber das spielte in der Wahrnehmung Reich-Ranickis für mich nie eine Rolle. Im Vordergrund stand immer die Persönlichkeit als solche.